# Casting a deserialized object

Tags: c#, casting, json.net

I have a PersistenceHandler, which implements different types of persistence (at least it is going to)
However, i ran into some problems loading from a file.

Code from PersistenceHandler:

```
static public object Load(string fileName)
{
    return _persistence.Load(fileName);
}
```

Which uses this method from JsonPersistence:

```
public object Load(string fileName)
{
    string readAllText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);    
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<EnumCategories, CategoryViewModel>>(readAllText);    
}
```

This works fine. As long as i want to serialize to the specified type.
But when i want to use it for any type of object, i cant make it work.
I have tried using declaring the type as object instead, and then cast it at its 'destination'

Like so:

```
Employees = (List<EmployeeModel>)PersistenceHandler.Load(_fileName);
```

I get a casting exception (I am ofc loading the json that contains the correct information)

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KanbanBoard.Model.EmployeeModel]'.

The only way i can get it to work is either by casting it where i deserialize it in my JsonPersistence class, or using the newtonsoft classes to convert it back and forth, at the destination point (like the example above.

Which would be fine - except i am trying really hard to make my program as easy to add features to as possible.

My entire project on github: https://github.com/Toudahl/KanbanBoard
EDIT: I am currently working in the refactoring branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your method as

```
public T Load<T>(string fileName)
{
    string readAllText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(readAllText);
}
```

Now it can be used like:

```
Employees = PersistenceHandler.Load<List<EmployeeModel>>(_fileName);
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the perfect solution :)
We havnt learned much about creating generic stuff yet - i thought i was only classes that could use <T> - i feel silly for not trying the same on a method